# How to check range within range inclusively in perl?

Tags: perl, range

I want to check the ranges over other ranges. For example:

To be checked:

```
   check1: 10-50
   check2: 100-150
   check3: 500-600
```

The place to check:

```
   range1: 49-100
   range2: 800-900
```

I want to check each number in check1 if present in range1 or range2 and so on. If any of the numbers is present then print the range. For here: 50 in check1 is present in range1. 100 is check2 is present in range1. But check 3 is not present in either of range1 or range2. How can this be achieved?

I started like this with data in 4 columns:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use v5.16;


my (@check1, @check2, @range1, @range2);

my $header = <DATA>;
foreach (<DATA>){
    chomp $_;
    my @columns = split "\t", $_;



    #check (check1 to check2) in range (all range1 to range2) both inclusive
    #check 3631 5899 in all range1 to range2, if found print YES
    #check 3760 5630 in all range1 to range2, if found print YES

}

__DATA__
#check1 check2  range1  range2
3631    5899    4706    5095
3760    5630    5174    5326
3631    3913    7834    8989
```

Comment: Please show what you are trying to do and why it is not working.  This is deal with SO, you can get help on specific problems with _your code_. (You should also explain where data is coming from etc.)

Comment: `my $range = Set::IntSpan('49-100,800-900'); if ($range->intersect('10-50')) { ... }`  or `my $range = Set::IntSpan([[49,100],[800,900]]); if ($range->intersect([[10,50]])) { ... }`

Comment: in your text it sounds like you want to check the check1 range against all of range1, range2, range3, but in your code it sounds like you only want to check the check1-check2 range on a line against the range1-range2 range on that line.  can you explain?  also add what your expected output it; that may clarify.

Comment: @ysth Yes you are correct, check each check1-check2 in all range1-range2 one by one. Thanks

Comment: do you really want it just to print a bunch of YES lines with no indication of which check range was a yes?  Show sample output.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would handle this:

```
my @checks = (
        [qw(check1 10 50)],
        [qw(check2 100 150)],
        [qw(check3 500 600)]);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($name, $min_r, $max_r) = split (' ', $line);
    print $name;
    foreach my $check (@checks) {
        print " $check->[0]" if overlap($min_r, $max_r, $check->[1], $check->[2]);
    }
    print "\n";
}

sub overlap {
    my ($r1, $r2, $c1, $c2) = @_;
    return 1 if $r1 >= $c1 && $r1 <= $c2;
    return 1 if $r2 >= $c1 && $r2 <= $c2;
    return 1 if $r1 < $c1 && $r2 > $c2;
    return 0;
}

__DATA__
range1 49 100
range2 800 900
```

Edit:
It seems you do not like my answer. Here is another proposition using the strange 4 columns data format (I do not see why you would have the same number of checks and of ranges) and reversing the role of checks and ranges as you said in one of your answers. I print a YES if the check is present in one of the ranges. If you want a YES if a check is present in all the ranges you just need to add 2 negations:

```
my @checks;
my @ranges;
my $header = <DATA>;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($min_c, $max_c, $min_r, $max_r) = split (' ', $line);
    push @checks, [$min_c, $max_c];
    push @ranges, [$min_r, $max_r];
}

foreach my $check (@checks) {
    print "$check->[0] $check->[1] YES\n"
        if grep {overlap($check->[0], $check->[1], $_->[0], $_->[1])} @ranges;
}

__DATA__
#check1 check2  range1  range2
3631    5899    4706    5095
3760    5630    5174    5326
3631    3913    7834    8989
```